# Javascript Finding if Function/Class exists before calling it

Tags: javascript, function, exists

I know how to check to see if a property of the global context exists. Any variation of

```
if (typeof myFunction != 'undefined'){...}
```

but what if I don't know the name of the function? I think globally I could do this

```
if (typeof this['myFunction'] != 'undefined'){...}
```

but I don't know how to do that in a function like this

```
function load(functionName){
  if (typeof GLOBALCONTEX[functionName] != 'undefined'){
    GLOBALCONTEX[functionName](arg1 , arg2 , ...);
  }
}
```

And I don't want to use try/catch as I have heard it is slow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If working with a browser, substitute `GLOBALCONTEX` with `window`. Example:

```
function load(functionName){
  if (typeof window[functionName] != 'undefined'){
   window[functionName](arg1 , arg2 , ...);
  }
}
```

Comment: The question is about calling a global function using it's name as a string, that's why it's not "just as good" as just calling the function as an object.

Comment: @katspaugh: That's why I removed it. ;)

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer as it is the best response. Quick question, what percent of javascript viewings are down via a browser? 99%? 50%? more, less?

Answer (score 0):

In the browser, the global object is [`window` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window). If you use another JavaScript execution environment (like Node.js), have a look at its documentation to find out the name/reference to the global object.

Of course such a test only works for functions which are defined in global scope, not in any higher scope. So it might be that such a function is available (and accessible) but it is not in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

The Globalcontext is window. All objects are attached to it.

```
function load(functionName){
      if (typeof window[functionName] != 'undefined'){
        window[functionName](arg1 , arg2 , ...);
      }
    }
```

Comment: As a few people pointed out this is not always the case (Although it probably is 99% of the time)